# Bash wget filter specific word

Tags: bash, sed, grep, wget

i want to filter a specific word from a website using wget.

the word i want to filter out is **hPa** and the value of it.

see: https://www.foreca.de/Deutschland/Berlin/Berlin

i can't find useful information on how to filter out a specific string.

this is what i've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST=$(wget -l1 https://www.foreca.de/Deutschland/Berlin/Berlin -O - | sed -e 'hPa')
echo $LAST
```

thanks for helping me out.

Comment: suggestion: 1) add few lines that contain `hPa` to question and show what is the expected output for those lines... 2) most likely you'll be better off using xml parsers instead of trying to solve using regex

Comment: post the final expected value of `$LAST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully fledged solution using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

### Command :

```
$ saxon-lint --html --xpath '//div[contains(text(), "hPa")]/text()' \
    'https://www.foreca.de/Deutschland/Berlin/Berlin'
```

### Output :

```
1026 hPa
```

### Notes :

- Don't parse HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser like we do here. Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- Check https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint (my own project)

---

[image] if what I wrote bores you and you just want a quick and dirty command even if it's evil, then use `curl -s https://www.foreca.de/Deutschland/Berlin/Berlin | grep -oP '\d+\s+hPa'`

Comment: This is not _that_ reliable as other one, but it's OP/your choice ;)